# Independent component analysis to separate objects from frame

Tags: python, image, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I have 200 frames of (100*100 ) each in a numpy array of (200, 100, 100).
The frames have circles at random positions, mixed with noise. I want to extract the circles from these frames using Independent Component analysis.
I tried working it with sklearn FastICA, it gives random mixed frame instead of separated out circles.

I was expecting each linear combination(lc_test) to give circles (separated out) from each frame but it is giving random frames.
   input: [image] output code is giving (incorrect): 
[image]

```
import numpy as np
import random
from sklearn.decomposition import FastICA, PCA

#Creating Data
def createCircle(width,height , rad ):
  w = random.randint(1, height)
  h = random.randint(1, height)
  center = [int(w), int(h)]
  radius = rad
  Y, X = np.ogrid[:height, :width]
  dist_from_center = np.sqrt((X - center[0])**2 + (Y-center[1])**2)
  mask = dist_from_center <= radius
  return mask

def addCircle(test_image):
  m = createCircle(width = 100, height = 100 , rad = 8 )
  masked_img = test_image.copy()
  masked_img[m] = 0
  return masked_img


def noise(image):
  row,col= image.shape
  mean = 0
  var = 0.1
  sigma = var**0.5
  gauss = np.random.normal(mean,sigma,(row,col))
  gauss = gauss.reshape(row,col)
  noisy = image + gauss #adding gauss noise
  s1 = np.sin(8)   #adding sin fill
  noisy += s1
  return noisy

 img = np.zeros([100,100],dtype=np.uint8)
 img.fill(20)
 img_test = img

 #Making 200 frames
 ims = np.zeros((200, 100, 100)) # initialize your array

 for i in range(1,200):
   for j in range(1,5):
     img_test = addCircle(test_image=img_test)
 im1 = noise(img_test)
 img_test = img
 ims[i, ...] = im1

 print(ims.shape) #(200,100,100)



#Apply Independent Component Analysis on ims
ims_flat = ims.reshape(200,10000)

ica_test = FastICA(max_iter = 3000, tol = 0.3)
s_test= ica_test.fit_transform(ims_flat.T)  #source matrix
print(s_test.shape) #(10000, 200)
a_test = ica_test.mixing_  #mixing matrix
print(a_test.shape) #(200, 200)

#unmixing matrix : inverse of mixing matrix
w_test = np.linalg.inv(a_test) #unmixing matrix
print(w_test.shape) #(200, 200)

#Taking Linear combination of unmixing matrix and ims_flat(original)  to extract Independent components
lc_test = np.linalg.solve(w_test, ims_flat) #Linear combinations
print(lc_test.shape) #(200, 10000)

#plotting Linear combinations
for i in range(1,200):  #Does not extract circles
  plt.imshow(lc_test[i,:].reshape(100, 100))
  plt.show()
```

The goal is to extract/separate circles from all 200 frames.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.
"does not give the results" is not a problem specification.  Please supply your debugging trace, output, etc.

Comment: I have attached the full code of the problem . It should reproduce the problem when run. i would go through the MCVE guidelines and make required changes.